# What is the process named SEPDRV_ABNORMAL under Linux?

Tags: process

Today, I ran `ps -ef` and I noticed that one of my Ubuntu 18.04 processes was named `SEPDRV_ABNORMAL`.

Any idea what that process would be?

```
root      5796     2  0 11:11 ?        00:00:00 [SEPDRV_ABNORMAL]
```

It sounds like a driver that failed, but I just cannot figure out much at all from that name. Google returns one Japanese website and the point did not seem to be about that specific entry. Nothing else about that name.

Process 2 is the kernel thread daemon:

```
root         2     0  0 11:11 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
```

---

**Update:** I upgraded my system to Ubuntu 20.04 since 18.04 is EOL very soon anyway, and it still shows that same process...

Comment: grepping through the kernel source may shed some light on that.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I tried and did not find anything with that full name. There are _many_ "ABNORMAL" macros (#define ...) but no strings. I was also thinking it could come from a proprietary driver, since I have NVidia... I had another one, but I removed it and I still have this weird process.

Comment: Did you rebuild your initrd and reboot after removing the driver? You might also grep through the `/lib/modules` tree of your kernel.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Good point! That being said, now that I've upgraded to version 20.04, I'm sure it has rebuilt everything as expected and the module is not loaded. Yet, the `ps -ef` still shows that process.